# CSS underline is not moving on click

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create sliding horizontal line on click of hyperlinks. Please have a look at:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JdEPPb

The HTML is:

```css
    * {
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    
    body {
      font: 300 100% 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial;
    }
    
    .container {
      width: 50%;
      margin: 0 auto;
    }
    
    ul li {
      display: inline;
      text-align: center;
    }
    
    a {
      display: inline-block;
      width: 25%;
      padding: .75rem 0;
      text-decoration: none;
      color: #333;
    }
    
    .one:active ~ hr {
      margin-left: 0%;
    }
    .two:active ~ hr {
      margin-left: 25%;
    }
    
    .three:active ~ hr {
      margin-left: 50%;
    }
    
    .four:active ~ hr {
      margin-left: 75%;
    }
    
    hr {
      height: .25rem;
      width: 25%;
      margin: 0;
      background: tomato;
      border: none;
      transition: 0.3s ease-in-out;
    }
```

```html
    <div class="container">
      <ul>
        <li class="one"><a href="#">Uno</a></li><!--
     --><li class="two"><a href="#">Dos</a></li><!--
     --><li class="three"><a href="#">Tres</a></li><!--
     --><li class="four"><a href="#">Quatro</a></li>
        <hr />
      </ul>
    </div>
```

There is no javascript code.

When I click Two, I want the underline to move under Two but currently its not moving. I need to hold for longer for it to move and when I release the mouse left button, it falls back to One

Comment: The desired effect is trivial with JS. If you want a css only approach, you will need to use another technique like using checkboxes or  the `:target` pseudo class.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`:active` only fires while you hold down the mouse button on the element - i.e. while you are actively clicking on the element.

You can use `:target` instead of `:active`.

The `:target` pseudo selector in CSS matches when the hash in the URL and the id of an element are the same.

By giving values to the `href` attribute of the links and `id`s of the `li` elements we can `:target` the `li` that has been clicked on:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font: 300 100% 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial;
}

.container {
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

ul li {
  display: inline;
  text-align: center;
}

a {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 25%;
  padding: .75rem 0;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #333;
}

#uno:target ~ hr {
  margin-left: 0%;
}
#dos:target ~ hr {
  margin-left: 25%;
}

#tres:target ~ hr {
  margin-left: 50%;
}

#quatro:target ~ hr {
  margin-left: 75%;
}

hr {
  height: .25rem;
  width: 25%;
  margin: 0;
  background: tomato;
  border: none;
  transition: 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <ul>
    <li class="one" id="uno"><a href="#uno">Uno</a></li><!--
 --><li class="two" id="dos"><a href="#dos">Dos</a></li><!--
 --><li class="three" id="tres"><a href="#tres">Tres</a></li><!--
 --><li class="four" id="quatro"><a href="#quatro">Quatro</a></li>
    <hr />
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: This is all very interesting/new to me... what is the ` ~ hr` meaning?

Comment: HC_, hr style in css is being applied to <hr /> in HTML. @Richard, one question, by any chance is it possible to get rid of using id for li elements

Comment: @HC_ `~` is a sibling selector similar to `+` except it will target a sibling of any distance (whereas `+` only targets the immediate sibling).

Comment: @Sandeep You could move the `hr` out of the `ul` and place some empty `span`s with the ids. That would make the html look a mess (imo).

Answer (score 9):

It moves while your mouse is still down. Your problem is that `:active` selector is only activated while the element is active, typically when the mouse is pressed.

You need to add the class `.active` instead of the `:active` selector. So you'd have:

```
.one.active ~ hr {
  margin-left: 0%;
}
.two.active ~ hr {
  margin-left: 25%;
}

.three.active ~ hr {
  margin-left: 50%;
}

.four.active ~ hr {
  margin-left: 75%;
}
```

And add some functionality:

```
var elems = document.querySelectorAll(".one,.two,.three,.four");
for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
  elems[i].addEventListener("click",function(e){
    if(document.querySelector(".active")){
      document.querySelector(".active").classList.remove("active");
    }
    e.currentTarget.classList.add("active");
  });
}
```

A pen: http://codepen.io/vandervals/pen/wagwBQ

Answer (score 3):

here is your solution to get active link when menu is in active state.
Issue with your code is that...you have use `:` selector instead use `.` selector.
also need to use little javascript.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GJrKjB

Answer (score 2):

Try this [Fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/stanze/w08fpay1/)

```
$('ul li').on('click', function() {
    $('li').removeClass('active')
    $(this).addClass('active')
})
```